# Is it possible to use LASSO regression with multi-levlel data?

Tags: machine-learning, multilevel-analysis, lasso

I have real-time monitoring data where participants report on a variety of variables four times per day for a month. Is it possible to use LASSO regression (e.g,. glmnet r package) with this data? I'm interested in seeing which of 15 level-1 variables (i.e., responses within people) are most relevant as correlates of another level-1 variable measured at the same time. There are no level-2 predictors.

I've seen this answer for panel data ([Dealing with hierarchical (panel, multi-level) data and fixed effects in LASSO?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/126549/dealing-with-hierarchical-panel-multi-level-data-and-fixed-effects-in-lasso)) but I'm not sure that it is similar enough to my data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evan! Hi! It's Sam B, former resident of one-office-over. Funny meeting you here. Did you ever find a solution to your problem? In googling, I discovered both your question and [this R package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/glmmLasso/glmmLasso.pdf), which seems to have been released since your post.

Comment: Thanks Sam! Good to hear from you and yep! This is exactly what I found.